# How to get multiple checkbox values in jquery

Tags: jquery

We are trying to add multiple select filters to apply button for layered navigation in Magento 2.1.0 with Smile Elastic Suite.

I have created a jQuery script to get all multiple selected option and split taking only params in array like below.

> first_filter_name=325,first_filter_name=326,first_filter_name=327,second_filter_name=225,second_filter_name=228

So now how to convert this array and make single url with repeated params?
Expected url will be :`http://localhost.com/page.html?first_filter_name[0]=72&first_filter_name[1]=83&first_filter_name[2]=84&second_filter_name[0]=brand1&second_filter_name[1]=brand2`.

Our filters look like

My script is like :

```
 $(".apply-filters").on("click",function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
            var val=[];
            var queryString= [];
            var hash;
            $("input[name='type']:checked").each(function() {                    
            val.push($(this).val().slice($(this).val().indexOf('?') + 1).split('&'));

            });
           alert(val);
        });
```

Alert result is:

> isconsumablefor=325,isconsumablefor=326,isconsumablefor=327,sets_pcs=225,sets_pcs=228

So help me to create single url to load products using filter params

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the snippet below. Basically the idea is to fetch all checkboxes with the appropriate selector (in my sample, `[data-my-form] input[type="checkbox"]:checked`, but can be anything else), and then call `jQuery.serialize()` on them.

The `decodeURIComponent` part is just for `console.log`, you don't want to decode that if you're gonna use it as an actual URL.

Note that inputs' names could all be `foo[]` (without indexes) and that would also generate a valid URL.

```js
let queryString = $('[data-my-form] input[type="checkbox"]:checked').serialize();

console.log(decodeURIComponent(queryString));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form data-my-form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo[0]" value="1" checked />
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo[1]" value="2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo[2]" value="3" checked />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to create the array of values and then use `join` to concat into a string:

```js
(function() {          
  var url = $('input[type="checkbox"]') // get all checkboxes
               .filter(':checked')  // get only checked
               .toArray()  // convert jQuery collection to array
               .reduce(function(acc, val) {        
                  acc.push('input[' + val.id + ']=' + val.value);
                  return acc;
               }, [])
               .join('&'); // join to string
  console.log(url);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="0" type="checkbox" value="100" checked />
<input id="1" type="checkbox" value="200" />
<input id="2" type="checkbox" value="300" checked />
<input id="3" type="checkbox" value="400" checked />
<input id="4" type="checkbox" value="500" checked />
```

Comment: yes above script will work but sorry before i did'nt share full address like :

Comment: yes above script will work but sorry before i did not shared proper, i have multiple filters checkbox so i am selecting and click "apply-filters" button then i getting full path url for each selection like: "http://localhost/magento2/shop/boards/plywood.html?grade=MR" and "http://localhost/magento2/shop/boards/plywood.html?grade=BR" so i have to get only after "?" and if repeated like above url to store in one like"grade[0]=MR&grade[1]=BR" . i tried to add in ur script to cut value but i am getting elem.node not function

Comment: how to split or get part of checkbox value ???.now i am getting like below `input[undefined]=http://localhost/site1_dev/index.php/shop/accessories/kitchen.html?sets_pcs=228&input[undefined]=http://localhost/site1_dev/index.php/shop/accessories/kitchen.html?sets_pcs=229&input[undefined]=http://localhost/site1_dev/index.php/shop/accessories/kitchen.html?sets_pcs=295` which i want get like "sets_pcs[0]=228&set_pcs[1]=229&other-attribute[0]=1"

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = 
$("input[name=cbxName]:checked")
.get()
.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue){
     accumulator.push(currentValue.value);
     return accumulator;
},[]);
```

or

```
var values = 
$("input[name=cbxName]:checked")
.toArray()
.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue){
     accumulator.push(currentValue.value);
     return accumulator;
},[]);
```

result example =>
values = ["Hourly", "Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly", "Yearly"]